# Redirect / and index.html to a new new url

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect 301 the index.html and the / to new-url.html on the same domain.

Actually I have

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.domain.com/new-url.html
```

This works. But when I add

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/new-url.html
```

it doesn't work and this is the result

```
http://www.domain.com/new-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.htmlnew-url.html
```

What's wrong with my redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead for regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(index\.html)?$ http://www.domain.com/new-url.html
```